# PrimeNg TabMenu Angular 11: set last tab on the right

Tags: angular, sass, primeng, tabmenu

I am using **Angular 11** and **PrimeNG** and styling with **Flex**.

From **PrimeNG** I am working now with **TabMenu**.

Imagine now I want to put three tabs: Tab 1, Tab 2 and Tab 3. I want to have on the left of the browser Tab 1 and Tab 2 and on the right I want only Tab 3.

I am using the next styles:

```
.p-tabmenu .p-reset {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: red !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and li childs:

```
.p-tabmenu .p-reset > li:nth-child(5)  {
  float: right;
}
```

thisd style angular is not recognizing and I don't understand why.

how can I set Tab 3 on the right using Flex? or maybe with some property of **TabMenu**?

Comment: try `:host >>> .p-tabmenu .p-reset > li:nth-child(5)`

Comment: whats the meaning of >>>?

Comment: While searching a definition to `>>>` (Its just an alias to `::ng-deep`.), I came across with this blog https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/  that says that it will be deprecated soon, so I'm taking back my former comment.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found in CSS is:

```
.p-tabmenu .p-reset {
  position: relative;
}

.p-tabmenu .p-reset > li:nth-child(5)  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  
}
```

with that worked.